# Javascript :Daterange min 1 year

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to set the date range 'fromdate' to 'afterdate' for my datepicker to be minimum 1 year. Im using bootstrap as for the datepicker and already set the input type id 'fromdate' and 'afterdate' to be call in javascript function. 
Here is what I manage to do it:

```
<div class="input-append success date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $_POST['fromdate'] ?>" name="fromdate" id="fromdate" style="width:185px;">
  <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span>
</div> 

<div class="input-append success date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $_POST['nextdate'] ?>" name="nextdate" id="nextdate" style="width:185px;">
  <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span>
</div> 


<script>
    function validateReportRangeForm(){
      var x = document.forms["daterange"]["fromdate"].value.trim();
      var y = document.forms["daterange"]["nextdate"].value.trim();

      var x = x.split("-").reverse().join("/");
      var y = y.split("-").reverse().join("/");
      if ((Date.parse(x) > Date.parse(y))) {
        alert("'From Date' should be greater than 'To Next Days'");
        document.forms["daterange"]["nextdate"].focus();
        return false;
      }
}
</script>
```

[image]

> Output:

[image]

Comment: Which part are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: I dont know how to set the minimum date range for 'nextdate' input field only read one (1) year from 'fromdate' input field.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make sure that the user cannot select a `nextdate` that is less than 1 year ahead of `fromdate`? If so, do you want this validation in PHP as well or just in JS?

Comment: I just want this to perform only in JS only sir